# Swift Memory Location in Xcode - String Summary

Tags: swift, xcode

I am trying using Xcode debug more efficiently. I realised some extra features which I have ever done before.
From my understanding left side of debug console called **String Summary** ( please correct me if i wrong). I watched the WWDC videos but could not see the direct approaches to this section

```
var robGlobal = Player(name: "Rob", health: 10, energy: 10)

robGlobal.someFunction()  // in viewdidload


struct Player {
    var name: String
    var health: Int
    var energy: Int

    func balance(_ x: inout Int, _ y: inout Int) {
        let sum = x + y
        x = sum / 2
        y = sum - x
    }
}

        func someFunction() {
            var robLocal = Player(name: "Rob", health: 10, energy: 10)
            balance(&robLocal.health, &robLocal.energy)  // put the breakpoint here
        }
```

If I click the right click of the mouse; It appears an option "View memory of ... ". After next steps I added the screen shot and made 4 section to ask better question.

**Q1**: Why there is a 10 line ? 16F34BDA0 is obvious. it correspond to name but what about 16F34BDD7 second line and so on ?

**Q2**: Would you mind if you explain with detail section 1-2-3 ?

**Q3**: Also name and robLocal is showing same place in the memory ? Is that possible ? - then why health and energy has different ?

[image]

Comment: @matt can you help for this question please ?

Answer (score 1):

- Section 1 contains memory locations
- section 2 contains binary
- section 3 contains text representation of the binary or the binary decoded into text

all of this is for the computer to read and is difficult for humans to understand. if you are trying to debug more efficiently, do yourself a favor and stay away from reading the binary in hex code and stick to the debugging bar at the bottom of the screen.

*edit:*
you can find the memory locations of variables by clicking the 'i with a circle' on the String Summary. this should help you match up the memory locations in section 4 with the variables in the String Summary. Also if I were to guess, one of the memory locations were self, one robLocal, and one the program itself in memory being executed.

Comment: IMO this is not a true approach and not answer for my question. i already see the contains binary but i am trying to understand relationship between them. Not necessary going to very low level but i want to have an idea about these sections and with String Summary.

Comment: ah i understand. you can find the memory locations of variables by clicking the 'i with a circle' on the String Summary. this should help you match up the memory locations in section 4 with the variables in the String Summary. Also if i were to guess, one of the memory locations were `self`, one `robLocal`, and one the program itself in memory being excuted.